# Outlook appointment as exchange server level

Tags: .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-2003

I would like to make a form which can send a reminder to a specific user's Exchange Outlook account when a button is clicked on a webpage.

Is this possible?  Is EWS the best approach?

I am using Exchange 6.5, Outlook 2003, and .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange 6.5 is Exchange 2003. The best approach is to use WebDAV protocol, but not easy.
There is a [library](http://www.independentsoft.de/webdavex/index.html) available for that. This might be your best option.